# Hibernate tutorials version 5.0.6 is not working

Tags: hibernate

When I tried to run the example in Hibernate tutorials (https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/quickstart/html/hibernate-tutorials.zip), it failed due to a ClassNotFound exception. I have checked the dependency and the class (CoreMessageLogger) was available.

Can anyone help on this issue? Thanks in advance.

I am using JDK 1.8 update 66 and Maven 3.3.9.

The exception is:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/transaction/SystemException
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
at org.jboss.logging.Logger$1.run(Logger.java:2554)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Logger.java:2529)
at org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Logger.java:2516)
at org.hibernate.internal.CoreLogging.messageLogger(CoreLogging.java:28)
at org.hibernate.internal.CoreLogging.messageLogger(CoreLogging.java:24)
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.<clinit>(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:40)
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder.build(BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder.java:207)
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.<init>(StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.java:58)
at org.hibernate.tutorial.hbm.NativeApiIllustrationTest.setUp(NativeApiIllustrationTest.java:48)
at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:139)
at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:122)
at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:142)
at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:125)
at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:129)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:255)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:250)
at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:84)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.transaction.SystemException
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the dependency in your `pom.xml`.It should work

```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
      <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
      <version>1.1</version>
  </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed the `jta.jar`.Try to add the `jta.jar` in your lib folder or add the dependency for this jar in your pom.xml. This contains the javax/transaction/SystemException